# Exlude package from maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, jfxtras

I have error `java: module com.example.learningfx reads package jfxtras.labs.util.event from both vworkflows.fx and jfxtras.labs` and I think I need to exclude package from jfxtras.labs or vworkflow.fx. Jow can I not include some packages from dependency? Do I need to make this in pom.xml or module-info.java? I use maven and IntelliJ. I think there is already some questions like this but I don't find it

Comment: Look for <exclusion> in Maven.  https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Answer (score 0):

See https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Exclusions

You do not provide complete groupId:artifactId:version coordinates, so the example cannot be exact:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>vworkflows.fx</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.jfxtras</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfxtras.labs.util.event</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
...
```

Comment: Is this exclusion need to be in jfxtras dependence or vworkflow? For jfxtras groupdID : org.jfxtras For artifactID is : jfxtras-labs And for version : 9.0-r1

Comment: The example I gave is how to exclude a transitive dependency in Maven pom.xml. In my practice, I have never seen Maven complaining that it finds the same transitive dependency (even with different versions) through different paths. If it does, it takes the dependency with the higher version and leaves only one of them in the path. So I guess the Java compiler issues the error message, and you are using Java 9+. Please address Java documentation for it if the fix above does not help.

Answer (score 0):

You can only include/exclude whole dependencies, not packages from dependencies.

Comment: But if so what exclude do inside dependency? You just exclude dependency that you just unclude? I think that makes no sense